# Does anyone have copy-paste between screen-shared Macs working when using "Push Through" with macOS Monterey 12.4?

Tags: copy-paste, monterey, screen-sharing

## Before AND After installing Version 12.4

I use Screen Sharing (full screen) on my Mac Mini (M1, 2020) to connect (via LAN) to my iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015).

- My Mac Mini screen sits to the left of my iMac screen.
- Once connected, I can use the keyboard/mouse (connected to the M1) to manipulate the iMac (which has no connected keyboard or mouse) **BUT FIRST** I change the M1's Mission Control desktop to display the iMac desktop (i.e., show the same iMac screen on the M1 monitor and iMac):

  - I can manipulate the iMac screen remotely (using the M1 mouse/keyboard).
  - I can copy (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) data from one machine and paste (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) the data into the other machine (in either direction).

## After installing 12.4 on Both Machines

As before, I can adjust the M1 Mission Control desktop to display the iMac screen (both the M1 and the iMac showing the same screen). I can manipulate the iMac **AND** copy-paste data in either direction.

### Improved Screen Sharing, but no Copy-Paste

- Now, I can use *"push through"*. As the mouse traverses right across the M1 screen, when the mouse reaches the right edge of the M1 screen IT CONTINUES onto the left edge of the adjacent iMac screen WITHOUT having to change the M1's Mission Control Desktop. [The M1 shows a Mission Control desktop that IS NOT the iMac desktop.]
- Once the cursor is "on" the iMac screen, the mouse and keyboard attached to the M1 operates the iMac (very cool).
- In this new mode of operation, copy-paste is not intuitive:

  - I cannot copy-paste data (in either direction) between the M1 and the iMac when using "push through" to switch the mouse/keyboard focus between the two machines.
  - I CAN continue to use copy-paste BUT ONLY if I adjust the M1's Mission Control desktop to display the iMac screen.

## Question

Has anyone found a way to copy-paste between two machines when using the "push through" model (i.e., without having to change Mission Control desktops)?

Comment: Not sure I understand what "I change the M1's Mission Control desktop to display the iMac desktop" means? I assume you use screen sharing via the screen sharing application, how does Mission Control come into play here?

Comment: You are correct. I should say, "I change the M1's desktop to show the (iMac's full-screen) Screen Sharing desktop". With full-screen enabled, Screen Sharing behaves like Mission Control desktops wrt screen navigation. So, I tend to conflate the two terms.